# Algorithm to find maximal independent set on a hexagonal/benzenoid graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given a graph G=(V,E), I want to find all maximal sets of independent edges. In general, this can be achieved by brute-force methods that have exponential complexity. However, I am concerned only with bipartite benzenoid graphs; i.e, those formed by the carbon atoms of poly aromatic hydrocarbons. The problem of finding these maximal sets is equivalent to that of finding the maximal number of Clar's sextets (aromatic rings) in the structure, hence the interest of this application in chemistry. Are there more efficient algorithms to find the maximal set of independent edges in such a case?

Comment: Have you tried solving the problem? if so, what did you try?

Comment: How do you represent the aromatic rings in your graph?  I assume that vertices are atoms and edges are bonds.  Do you distinguish between single and double bonds?  Do you identify the atoms ( carbon, hydrogen, ... )?

Comment: ravenspoint: Aromatic rings will be those hexagons with three double bonds. Yes, vertices are atoms and edges are bonds. In the graph there are only carbons, not hydrogens (the idea is to represent the pi-conjugated system with the graph). The double bonds will be represented by a (independent) subset of the edges. It has to be independent due to the valence of the carbon atoms.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set up an adjacency list that makes finding node at other end of edge from a node easy and fast:

```
LOOP A over nodes
    IF A is carbon
        IF A has two or more bonds to another carbon
             IF A has one double bond to another carbon
                 Add A to list of potential ring members
LOOP A over list of potential ring members
    SET A2 to node at other end of double bond from A AND in list of potential ring members
    SET A3 to node at other end of single bond from A2 AND in list of potential ring members
    SET A4 to node at other end of double bond from A3 AND in list of potential ring members
    SET A5 to node at other end of single bond from A4 AND in  list of potential ring members    
    SET A6 to node at other end of double bond from A5 AND in list of potential ring members
    IF A6 == A
        add A...A6 to list of rings
        remove A...A6 from list of potential ring members
```

Note if any of the SETs are not possible, CONTINUE to next iteration of loop.

Comment: I understand this will be useful to detect the aromatic rings once the structure of double bonds is 'assigned'; but the real problem is, given the graph, to select a subset of the edges (the ones which will be double bonds) so that the number of aromatic rings is maximal. In that sense, if I haven't misunderstood, your answer cannot solve the problem.

Comment: Please describe clearly your data structure.  A small example would be good.  Between your question and a couple of comments, your description is very confusing.  And what on earth is a pi conjugated system?

Comment: The chemistry was mostly motivation to explain why the problem is of interest. The question, briefly put, is simply "how to find all maximal sets of independent edges" and, in particular, if in the case of hexagonal graphs (i.e, a bipartite graph where each site belongs to at least one 6-cycle and there are no smaller cycles) this search can be done more efficiently than for a generic graph (where the answer is well known).

Comment: You need to edit your question so that all these details are present in the question, not scattered around in comments.  An example or two always makes explanations easier to understand.